# Is it necessary to do NULL value check before doing comparison on a nullable column in database?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I am wondering if it is necessary or a good practice to perform null value check before doing comparison in database, especially on MySQL and MSSQL as I am working on those. Is there any performance impact if null check is performed?

In short, what is the difference between version 1 and version 2 in the following SQL for MySQL, in terms of the result produced and performance?

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS t1;

CREATE TABLE t1 (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    intval INT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    strval VARCHAR(32) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    KEY idx_intval (intval),
    KEY idx_strval (strval)
);

INSERT INTO t1 (intval, strval) VALUES
    (2, 'B'),
    (1, 'A'),
    (NULL, 'C'),
    (4, NULL);

-- Version 1
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE intval IS NOT NULL AND intval > 1;
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE strval IS NOT NULL AND strval IN ('A', 'C');

-- Version 2
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE intval > 1;
SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE strval IN ('A', 'C');

DROP TABLE t1;
```

Comment: Just keep in mind: In standard SQL NULL != NULL as NULL is a not defined -- It's like "I don't know and how to compare".

Comment: 1) See execution plan 2) NULL use with <>, >, <, != is always NULL 3) There is no  short-circuit evaluation in WHERE clause

Comment: Version 2 is perfectly fine. In most cases there's no need to do both IS NOT NULL and another comparison. But watch out, NOT IN sub-select fools many programmers!

Comment: `col NOT IN (NULL, 1) ` is the same as  `col <> NULL AND col <> 1` which is always NULL, Simple [The negation of a disjunction is the conjunction of the negations.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every comparison with NULL fails, if you don't use IS NULL / IS NOT NULL.

So:

`NULL > 1` fails (==> it isn't necessary to specify INTVAL IS NOT NULL)

`NULL IN ('A', 'C')` fails (==> it isn't necessary to specify STRVAL IS NOT NULL)

Comment: Will there any performance degrade if an unnecessary `IS NOT NULL` is specified? I tried to see the execution plan on MySQL and MSSQL as @lad2025 suggested but I can't see any difference, even though there is no short-circuit evaluation as suggested by @lad2025.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot compare with `null`, as `null` is an empty string. If you compare something with `null` result `null`.

Comment: The `NULL` value is something DIFFERENT from empty string.

Comment: nulls are nothing but an empty value

Comment: Incorrect, @Smart003.  `NULL` is a marker for the absence of a value.  An empty value `'` `'` is equivalent to another empty value, but two nulls are neither equal nor not equal to each other, and no real value is equal to *or not equal to* null, either.